# Possible bug with Stack Overflow User reputation

Tags: support, tags, reputation, api

I am working on a university project using the Stack Exchange API.
I get a number of the top users of every year starting from 2008, and I use the API to get their tags.

A strange thing that I noticed is that one user: [ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130591/ben) is in the #2437
position on the year 2008, but his only question was made at Jan 14 2009 and his only answer on Sep 28 2010.
Also when I am using the API [usage of /users/{ids}/tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-on-users#order=desc&sort=popular&ids=130591&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) to get his tags of the year 2008, it doesn't return any results (which is logical).

JSON request: `/2.2/users/130591/tags?fromdate=1199145600&todate=1230681600&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow`.

So why is he on the list of the top 2008 users without any activity on this year?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He only has one answer *that was not deleted*. And that is the 'problem' here. You see reputation from posts that are now deleted. You can see that reputation in his [reputation overview](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130591/ben?tab=reputation&sort=time).

If a post gets deleted, the reputation earned is not always deducted from the user's grand total. According to the [reputation faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238), the post has to have been visible for at least 60 days, and score at least 3 in order for the reputation earned to be preserved.

The tag score is removed though. Hence you don't see it in the tag API response.

Comment: OK i see. I think it would be nice preserving the tags as well. Anyway thanks a lot.